# Share only single screen with someone

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

So when I was on windows and working with a colleague I used to use Webex and would share my desktop, I could lock it down to showing only a single monitor - I can't find a equivalent on Ubuntu and was hoping someone could help...

My goal is to share only a single monitor ( I have two monitors currently setup in Ubuntu at present ). Ideally I'd like Remote desktop sharing to support selective sharing, but it seams to share the whole desktop so the viewer gets 2 1920x1080 screens side by side ... which can be unwieldy.

Is there any way to restrict Remote Desktop Sharing to this, or is there any other apps available that would do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com)? I've used this in the past as it is one of the few desktop sharing suites that works on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to use both of the screens, you can disable one of the monitors in order to have only one, while you present your webex.

What happened to me is that I was sharing both of the screens to all the connected users, which led me eventually to disable my screen and use the projector's screen in order to present the webex. (My users were seeing the resolution of both monitors)

I know it may not be pretty, but may be of help, instead of telling all of your users to install an extra software (especially when you are 5 minutes to start a presentation).

Process:

1. Go to the Display settings.
2. Identify the monitors by clicking on the info button.
3. Uncheck the monitor you won't use for your presentation.
4. Apply changes.
5. Re-share your desktop on webex.

I have Kubuntu 14.04.